# Get X rows from dataframe based on lowest values in specified column; and randomly select among ties

Tags: r

top_n in dplyr is doing almost what I want; however, when there are ties it returns all, but I would like it to randomly select among the ties to satisfy my cutoff of 2 rows.

```
top_number=4
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6)
y <- c(3, 2, 5, 1, 2, 3, 3)
xy <- data.frame(x, y) 
xy
xy_1 <- dplyr::top_n(xy, top_number, wt = x)
xy_1
```

Please note that the three 6s should always be selected in x and then the random selection should be among the two 3s.
Would be nice with a tidyverse solution.

Comment: Try with `distinct` `dplyr::top_n(xy, top_number, wt = x) %>% distinct`  Or may be `dplyr::top_n(xy, top_number, wt = x) %>% group_by(x) %>% slice(sample(row_number(), top_number))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting the `top_n` rows, we can `slice` based on random `sample`ing of the `row_number()`

```
library(dplyr)
top_n(xy, top_number, wt = x) %>% 
   arrange(desc(x)) %>% 
   slice(c(seq_len(top_number -1), sample(top_number:n(), 1)))
```

Comment: Please note that this answer does not select among the ties but among all numbers. I have updated the questions to be more clear.

Comment: @Gorp I previously had the `group_by(x)`, but removed only because of the example.  Updated

Comment: @Gorp Can you show your expected output.  Now, the `top_number` is specified as 4

Comment: thanks for the patience: I've added: Please note that the three 6s should always be selected in x and then the random selection should be among the two 3s. Does this make sense?

Comment: Thanks a lot for this!

Answer (score 3):

Another option could be:

```
xy %>%
 top_n(top_number, wt = x) %>%
 sample_n(top_number)
```

To address the updated question, with the addition of `purrr`:

```
xy %>%
 top_n(top_number, wt = x) %>%
 add_count(x, name = "n_all") %>%
 add_count(x, y) %>%
 group_split(n) %>%
 map_dfr(~ mutate(., cond = if_else(n != n_all, 1, top_number)) %>%
          sample_n(cond) %>%
          select(x, y))
```

Comment: Please note that this answer does not  select among the ties but among all numbers. I have updated the questions to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine with a deterministic solution, where the first rows with the minimum value are always selected, you can do it like this:

```
# non_random
xy %>% slice( order(desc(x)) %>% head(top_number) )
```

This approach ends up being much faster than using randomness to select between the group of rows with the minimum value.

However if you require randomness, but you don't require the result to be ordered, you can do it like this:

```
# random_unordered
xy %>% 
    top_n(top_number, x) %>% 
    slice(c( seq_len(n())[x != min(x)], 
             sample(seq_len(n())[x == min(x)], n() - top_number) ))
```

If you require both randomness and an ordered output, you can then use the solution provided by @akrun

I tested these 3 approach with microbenchmark, naming the first approach `non_random`, the second one `random_unordered` and akrun's one `random_ordered`. The tests were done across dataframes with different number of rows, and taking the median runtime of each approach over 100 executions. [Here are the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cggc0.png)